# can't figure out how to connect my bulma.sass to my main.sass file

Tags: css, bulma

This is the way i have it:

```
@import "D:/lifebooster/Mybulma/bulma-0.9.4/bulma/bulma.sass"
```

And this is the path copied:

"D:\lifebooster\Mybulma\bulma-0.9.4\bulma\bulma.sass"

I'm on a windows computer using vscode. When i try to follow link it says it can't be opened because the file was not found.

I just copied the path on file explorer and changed the \ to /